# how to update only a nested json element in supabase

Tags: rest, supabase, supabase-database

I have a Supabase's postgres database where a row contains a column called `jsonData` that has many `JSON` fields:

```
{
  "key1": "...",
  "key2": "...",
  "key3": "...",
  "key4": "..."
}
```

I want to update as an example only the `key3` with a new value and leave other properties as they are.

I tried making a new request getting the whole `JSON` object and manipulating it then updating the entire `jsonData` column, but this can result in updates with previous values if I have many updates running simultaneously.

I do use the Supabase REST API for this, I just don't know the best solution for updating a nested field directly without any workarounds.

and I want to know if I can do a custom PostgresSQL query for this.

Thank you and I appreciate any kind of help or guidance.

Comment: I would recommend using an RPC [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74352316/supabase-dynamic-rpc-function/74353089#74353089) for it.